# How to minimize the $2$-norm?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, compactness, convex-optimization

I encountered the following question today: 
Given $n$ real numbers $r_1\le ...\le r_n.$ Can we find $k_1,...,k_n \ge 0$ real with $\sum_{i=1}^n k_i=1$ such that
$$(r_1-k_1)^2+...+(r_n-k_n)^2$$
is minimal?

Is there a way to do this analytically or are there good optimization algorithms that can do this? (The problem has apparently a unique solution (compactness) and a unique-solution by convexity of the euclidean norm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are projecting the point $(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$ onto the probability simplex. This projection is needed often as a substep in convex optimization algorithms, and the solution can be found for example in this paper:

"[Projection onto the probability simplex:
An efficient algorithm with a simple proof, and an application](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.1541v1.pdf)"
by Wang and Carreira-Perpinan.

This paper provides the following Matlab code which projects each row vector in the $N × D$ matrix $Y$ onto the probability simplex in $D$ dimensions.

```
function X = SimplexProj(Y)
    [N,D] = size(Y);
    X = sort(Y,2,’descend’);
    Xtmp = (cumsum(X,2)-1)*diag(sparse(1./(1:D)));
    X = max(bsxfun(@minus,Y,Xtmp(sub2ind([N,D],(1:N)’,sum(X>Xtmp,2)))),0);
```

See also slide 8-12 of Vandenberghe's 236c notes:

http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/proxop.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Use Lagrange multipliers:
$$F(\mathbf{k},\lambda) = \|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{k}\|_2^2 - \lambda(\sum_{i}k_i-1).$$
Then
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial k_i}F(\mathbf{k},\lambda) = & 2(k_i - r_i) - \lambda,\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}F(\mathbf{k},\lambda) = & \sum_{i}k_i - 1.
\end{align}
The first equation is zero if, and only if
$$k_i = r_i + \frac{\lambda}{2}.$$
Then the other condition gives
$$1 = \sum_{i}k_i = \sum_{i}r_i + \frac{n}{2}\lambda,$$
so that $\lambda = \frac{2\left(1-\sum_{i}r_i\right)}{n}$. Therefore,
$$\mathbf{k} = \mathbf{r} + \frac{2\left(1-\sum_{i}r_i\right)}{n}\pmatrix{1\\\vdots\\1}.$$
This finds the solutions in the interior of the region where $\mathbf{k}$ is allowed to live. If you don't find any solution in the interior, then re-do all the process above on the boundary (where one or more $k_i$'s are zero).

Comment: you forgot the condition that $k_1,..,k_n \ge 0.$ Do you think you can build this into your neat approach?

Comment: @Optimization2.0 Added a paragraph explaining how to go on. I'll let you do the work, though.

Comment: I still think that there is something wrong in what you say. Imagine $\sum r_i =1$ then $k=r$ according to your algorithm. Now there is no need that all entries in $r$ are positive. Therefore, $k$ is not in the interior of the region where $k$ is allowed to live.

Comment: @Optimization2.0 Then, as I have written, there is no solution in the interior of the region, and you have to look for one constrained in the boundary.

Comment: For negative $r_i$, you simply set $k_i = 0$ and consider the problem where you leave out this term.